# Function get_permalink() not working properly in if statement (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on changing how posts in slider on this website (https://otwartakultura.org/) are linked. Now they can link only to post, but I would like to have possibility to link to other pages.

I have created a new field in ACF ('link'). I wrote if statement - when the 'link' field is not empty, use 'link' value; else: use post permalink.
It works for 'link" value, but for "else" it shows homepage url not post url.

Current working code:

```
 <article<?php
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        ?> style="background-image: url('<?php echo  the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>');"<?php
    } ?>>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
<header>
<div class="title-box">
        <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
    <span class="read-more">czytaj więcej ></span>
    </div></header></a>
</article>
```

Code I have tried to use:

```
<article<?php
      if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    ?> style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>');"<?php
    } ?>>

<a href="<?php
if (get_field( 'link' ) !==0) {
echo get_field( 'link' ); }
else {
echo get_the_permalink();
} ?>">

<header>
<div class="title-box">
        <h1><?php echo get_title(); ?></h1>
    <span class="read-more">czytaj więcej ></span>
    </div></header></a>
</article>
```

Please help :)

Comment: Do you have any errors ? When You open Chrome browser press `F12` And find console tab.

Comment: Im not an PHP programmer but i thing You might have wrong if statement. `if (get_field( 'link' ) !== 0)` there should not be `!= null` or `!= ""` ?

Comment: @Mises In console tab I get only one error connected with blocked piwik script.
After hanging to `!= null` or `!= ""` there is one difference: second or third slide is linking to the proper post and the other one still to homepage (first slide is linking according to what was inserted in "link" field)

Comment: You cannot assign link to 'get_the_permalink()' ? There should be in template 'for' loop can you edit and shot in post ? I dont know how data is structured. Try to paste more code. If at least one else works maybe i will solve it. XD

Comment: @Mises I have changed (and edited the question as well) `get_the_permalink()` to `get_permalink()` (as it is in currently working code), but there is no difference.
Here is [link](https://github.com/CCLab/otwartakultura.org/blob/master/home.php) to the whole home.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this will not work i just can't help you. You will need to pray to some php programmer.

```php
<a <?php if (get_field( 'link' ) != null) { ?> 
    href="<?php echo get_field( 'link' ); ?>"
<?php } else { ?>
    href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"
<?php } ?> >
```

Comment: Could you please explain me this concept a bit? I don't understand the idea of hardcoding elements that are taken from posts.

Comment: Just instead trying to put a link in a while loop put it before loop.

Comment: @KasiaW Sorry i was tired when i was writing this code. Edited again, Hope everything will be clear. And hope will solve your problem.

Comment: But I don't want to hardcode any articles. Homepage is showing 3 latest posts, and I just want to have option to decide, weather the homepage slider should link to that post or to some other place.

Comment: @KasiaW edited... This is my last solution if it not works give me a sign I'll delete answer so maybe someone responds.

Comment: @KasiaW No problem. For me no more php language in the future. XD